# is it ok to use the zookeeper within kafka in production?

Tags: apache-kafka

kafka has a zookeeper.
Is it ok to use it on production?

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh
```

I want to use SASL with kafka. However I cann't find a way to chieve it with the offical zookeeper. I did make it work with the kafka zookeeper. Therefore I want to know if it's ok to use the zookeeper which is in kafka on production environment.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Kafka requires Zookeeper to run. You can download Zookeeper independently from https://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the zookeeper that comes bundled with Apache Kafka is great for production use. No need to install any different version of zookeeper from anywhere else.